# Get output from last layer in each epoch in LSTM, Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

We are already aware that output of each layer can be obtained from following code:

```
def get_layer(model,x):
    from keras import backend as K

    get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                      [model.layers[2].output])
    layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([x])[0]
    print(layer_output.shape)
    return layer_output
```

LSTM model is fit as:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size,verbose=1, nb_epoch=10,validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

But how to obtain output of the last layer in the model for each epoch out of 10 epochs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom callback ([see Documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/)) and pass it to the callback list in the `fit` method.

Example:

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class LogThirdLayerOutput(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output(self.validation_data)[0]
        print(layer_output.shape)
```

And when fitting the model:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, nb_epoch=10, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), callbacks=[LogThirdLayerOutput()])
```

If you don't want to create the callback in a separate class, you should also be able to use [Lambda callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/#lambdacallback).

Comment: Can we get the `layer_output` from `training data` instead of `validation data` in `Callback` in this case ?